# GIT installation

Tags: git

How does the command "sudo apt-get install git" work on Ubuntu without downloading an executable GIT bash file on Ubuntu as that in Windows(where we download and install)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt` is a package manager. It automatically downloads the required packages from Ubuntu's repository servers (or additional locations you configured) in the background for you, and installs them.

For more information, here a few links:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto
- https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/apt.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(Debian)